# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): undefined is not an object ('prevComponentInstance._currentElement')

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

In react native I am trying to get json data using axios.get(my_url_path), then I'm update my state with response.data to 'urldatabase' key ,if I trying to call this state key and read the data from the json that I got I get the error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): undefined is not an object ('prevComponentInstance._currentElement')....
```

my code is as follow:

```
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userAnswer: '', count: 0, urldatabase: {} };
  }



  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('my_url_path')
      .then(response => this.setState({urldatabase: response.data}));
  }
  render() {
    let num = this.state.count;
    console.log(this.state.urldatabase[num].book)
    const book = this.state.urldatabase[num].book
     return(
        <RiddleHeader headerText={book} />
)
}
}
```

Can anyone please explain why am I getting this error? what I done wrong if any?

Comment: can you try to bind component did mount in your constructor? also please add the whole file with proper indentations.

after this.state = {...} in constructor, add this:

```javascript
this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider: In `componentWillMount`, what happens if the axios promise is rejected? Right: It's unhandled. You need a `catch` handler in there. The basic rule of promises: Always handle rejection or return the promise to the caller. In this case, since React won't do anything with it if you return the promise out of `componentWillMount`, you need to handle the error within `componentWillMount`.

Answer (score 0):

Rewite the code like this and check whether it happening again.

```
  }   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userAnswer: '', count: 0, urldatabase: {} };   }



  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('my_url_path')
      .then(response => this.setState({urldatabase: response.data}));   }   render() {
    let num = this.state.count;
    console.log(this.state.urldatabase[num].book)
    const book = this.state.urldatabase[num] && this.state.urldatabase[num].book; // this code can avoid undefined error
     return(
        <RiddleHeader headerText={book} /> ) } }
```